# Web Api won't serialize my Object Graph

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I got two simple entities:

```
public class Ingredient : IEntity
{
    public Ingredient()
    {
        Drinks = new List<Drink>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
}

public class Drink : IEntity
{
    public Drink()
    {
        Ingridients = new List<Ingredient>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingridients { get; set; }
    public string Approach { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Object graph for type 'Gudo.Core.Model.Ingredient' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.
```

I've tried using the `JsonIgnore` Attribute on the `Drinks` collection and I've tried using:

```
JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

In my global.asax

Nothing works..

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure to set this on the JSON formatter's serializer settings? This line should do it for you:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```